# Node accounting - open source or bitcoin software

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, business, python-bitcoinlib, community, accounting

I am running a LND node. experimenting for other almost 2 years with it.
i then started a small (2 persons) consulting company.
this node is now used to go on building expertise and trying stuff. it is now therefore a part of the company
-> **I need  to do some proper accounting** :

1 - establish the exact state of the node on the day of creation of the company ( 4 months ago ...)

2 - from  then,  get a detail report of all the transactions ( onchain, offchain, routing, fees ...) with dates.

3- from now on, same as point 2.

I tried using lncli commands . It is not easy to solve point 1 ( get a accountable state at the creation date).
I also can do some python programming, provided there is a reliable and complete data source.

Are they other commands/ tools to help ?
do you now of open source community / tools or bitcoin software that could help ? ( as I said i can also do some programming on top if necessary)

Thanks if you can help

tepeji